# Restoring vhd images containing LVM to physical machine

Tags: vhd, lvm

I have a **vhd** image previously converted from a Hyper-v **vhdx** image.
The vhd contains a Fedora core 20 installation with a standard **/boot** partition and a **LVM** containing **root** and **swap**. I use **Acronis true image** to restore the vhd to a real hard disk of another machine. The restore process is successful but after the reboot the boot stops at "dracut /dev/root does not exist" complaining about a wrong UUID. If I do **ls /dev/disk/by-uuid** I get one partition, the /boot one, the LVM is missing. After mounting /dev/sdc1 I get the linux boot stuff. But mounting the /dev/sdc2 results in "cannot mount lv_group".
In the restore options I chose the sector by sector option so I'm expecting a raw dump filling the other disk, but it parses the vhd omitting the LVM content, am I right? I don't think is an Acronis issue, I'm sure the same would happen with clonzilla or other solutions. Is there a way to really dump the vhd content bit by bit or briefly, how to convert a linux VM containing LVM to a physical machine on the fly, as it would contain standard partitions?

Comment: Just found out that a 30K Windows app can do it. It's vhd2disk and it does a perfect job! It copies block by block as I like it.

Comment: ...by the way...Clonezilla does not support vhd restoring, Acronis does only "high level" restoring from vhd (they name their image to disk as sector by sector, but it is not!). Is there a product that can just grab a vhd and dump the whole thing onto a physical disk just like vhd2disk and do it from a live-CD?

Comment: UPDATE: I was completely mistaken. Acronis does restore vhd with LVM inside it. The problem was the Fedora installation was made on IDE and I am trying to restore to SCSI.